# Connect to remote server and execute command

Tags: r, ssh, remote-access, rcurl

I am attempting to use R to ssh into a remote unix server from windows (I normally connect through PuTTY) and execute a command. I have already been able to write code to sftp files from this server to my local using the commands below:

```
data_bin <- getBinaryURL(file_remote, userpwd = credentials, 
                                       ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)
writeBin(data_bin, file_output)
```

However, the first function seems restricted to pointing to individual files. What I would like to do would be to connect to my remote server in a similar fashion, but this time pass on a command that I would normally execute at the command line? Can anyone point me to the correct methodology or resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the documentation from `?system`.

Just as an example, if I run the command sftp via `system()`:

```
   > system("sftp")
    usage: sftp [-1246aCfpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
              [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit]
              [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
              [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
           sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
           sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
           sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
```